# Why python shows Invalid token for datetime(2018,01,01,10,08,00)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2018,01,01,10,08,00)
```

The above code produces an error

```
>>> datetime(2018,01,01,10,08,0)
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

If i change `08` to any value between 01 and 07 then the error will not show and also the error will unshown if i change `08` to `8`.

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Time to upgrade to Python 3 - this form of octal literals is gone in the current version of the language. (instead of `010` you'd have to write `0o10`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because integer literals starting with a `0` are interpreted as octal numbers and the digit `8` is not allowed in an octal number.

Strip your leading zeros.  They have more meaning than you expected.